# How to inform google on upcoming penetration test

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are running our Software Application partially on google cloud platform and will be running a security review, which includes a penetration test soon.

We are tasked with informing our Hosting providers on this.

How should I do this for Google?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you are not obliged to [inform Google about your pen tests](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6262505?hl=en):

> If you plan to evaluate the security of your Cloud Platform
>   infrastructure with penetration testing, you are not required to
>   contact us.  You will have to abide by the Cloud Platform [Acceptable
>   Use Policy](https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup) and [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms/), and ensure that your tests only
>   affect your projects (and not other customers’ applications).  If a
>   vulnerability is found, please report it via the [Vulnerability Reward
>   Program](https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/reward-program/).

... therefore there's no actual formal way of doing this. Probably a good idea would be to contact Google Cloud Platform Support and re-check that, also to have a record of this action, as you say you were tasked to inform the cloud provider.

Comment: Hi Ania

Thank you for this comment, i did not see that information in the FAQ.